# What is the strategy of UK's universities for a post-Brexit world?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, education

Brexit is disrupting the activities of universities in the UK that are committed to support research, innovation and education networks, and it will be even more so after the actual exit on Friday 29th March.

Of course, the damages will depend on the scenario. Research, innovation and education networks will be hindered more badly in case of a no-deal.

But in any case, universities in the UK should be committed to strengthening their ties to collaborators abroad, and they might even size the opportunity for creating new partnerships with North American and Asian institutions. However,  Europe remains a major actor in research, so universities in the UK cannot neglect their European partnerships. Moreover, UK's universities have a long history of productive collaborations with their German and French counterparts for instance. So, here I would like to focus on European partnerships of UK's universities.

In this context, some of the top UK's universities want to mitigate the consequences of the Brexit and sustain research, innovation and education networks with their European partners, focusing in particular on sustainable partnerships.

I will break down the question in the title into three specific questions:

1. What is the strategy of research-intensive universities in the UK to retain access to a substantial pool of European fundings to sustain their research and innovation ?
2. What is the strategy of top universities in the UK to ease the mobility of researchers (from the EU to the UK and the other way around) ?
3. What is the strategy of top universities in the UK to ease student mobility and still attract bright students from the EU ?

Comment: In what way is it " clear that Brexit is disrupting the activities of universities in the UK that are committed to support research, innovation and education networks"?  A quick search shows a number of articles showing that there is concern about what might happen, but not what is or has happened.

Comment: Questions of "what should the priorities be" seem to a matter of opinion, rather than fact or judgement. This question seems likely to provoke discussion rather than answers.

Comment: VTC as opinion-based. StackExchange is organized as a question and answer site, not a discussion forum. Although it's an interesting topic, it needs to be asked in such a way users can tell what the "best" answer is. If you had multiple responses, how would judge which was the best?

Comment: @JamesK: I changed the title.

Comment: @indigochild: I have improved the question. I'm not looking for opinions, but for analyses that explain actual strategies that are currently implemented, or will be implemented, in some of the universities in the UK, in particular research-intensive universities which are also spin-off-friendly.

Comment: @RWW: in some sense it's already disruptive, researchers are worrried by the Brexit turmoil, some of them decline positions in the UK, some researchers try to avoid European grant proposals that are UK-heavy regarding their participants.

Comment: I voted to close because I think this might be too broad. Instead, try focussing on something specific. For example: *If any, what strategies have UK universities taken to maintain the flow of EU citizens coming to study in the UK?* This question is broad because there are many issues due to brexit (students coming in, EU-UK research partnerships, EU funding, etc.)

Comment: It's not like universities in existing non-EU countries can't partner with universities in EU countries.

Comment: @immibis: sure, but the prime schemes of collaboration and partnership between the UK and EU member states will have to change after the Brexit. This is the point.

Comment: @JJJ: thanks for your remarks and help. I see three distinct questions, each more specific, linked together in the context outlined but interesting in their own rights.

Comment: @immibis funding may be more difficult. Some projects require a number of EU countries to work together to get a grant. Previously, the UK would qualify for that so unis in other countries would be more compelled to partner with them. Now, other EU countries may be more attractive as UK unis might lack the funding.